# Array modifier - why is the source object tripled?

Tags: modifiers

I don't understand why is the source object: BaseDeco 1, tripled when I apply the array modifier, with offset based on an Empty (BaseDeco 1 Empty)? It is tripled - there are 3 sources from which the Array makes clones.

I thought the array should start from one object (in this case the BaseDeco 1 - when I go into edit mode, there is clearly only one piece), and go around making 20 copies, but it's tripled. Why and how to control it?

I simply need 20 copies going around the perimeter of the circle.

I'm attaching the Blend.

[image]

[image: Tripled source]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modifier works as intended in the file. The pieces overlap on top of each other because of the amount of rotation in the Z axis of the Offset Object. If you wanted 20 copies around it you need to rotate the offset object 360°/20=18°:

[image]